# When I call this function, I get this error: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at MethodInfo-1()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm new here, and very new to AS3. So here is my crazy question:

Why am I getting this error: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at MethodInfo-1()

for this function I'm working on:

```
    /* a universal function for all the movieclips */
function clickAndPlay(element):Function {

    /* return the click event */
    return function(e:Event):void {

        /* stop the event from propagating */
        e.stopPropagation();

        /* get the labels from the clip */
        var labels:Array = element.currentLabels;
        var numFrm:Number = labels.length; /* count them */

        /* if there are no labels for this clip, get the frame length instead */
        if(numFrm == 0) {
            /* get the number of frames */
            numFrm = element.totalFrames;
            trace(numFrm);
            if(element.currentFrame < numFrm) {
                element.nextFrame();
            }else{
                element.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        }else{
            /* get the current index of the labels array */
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < numFrm; i++) {
                if(labels[i].name == element.currentLabel) {
                    if(i < numFrm) {
                        /* get the next label's name */
                        var labelName:String = labels[(i+1)].name;
                        /* go to the next label */
                        trace(labelName);
                        element.gotoAndStop(labelName);
                    }else{
                        element.gotoAndStop(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know what the function is referring to. I've checked to make sure the label on the frame is accurate, and it is. I'm sure its something stupid, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Shaun

Comment: body02
body03
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at MethodInfo-1()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
if (i < (numFrm-1)) {
```

Rather than

```
if (i < numFrm) {
```

Otherwise the next line will cause an error when attempting to access labels[(i+1)]

Edit:

Consider the case where i = numFrm-1 (ie: the last iteration of the loop):

labels[(i+1)].name is the same as labels[(numFrm-1+1)].name or labels[numFrm].name

However, the length of labels is numFrm (thats where you got the value of numFrm from) so you are trying to access a non-existant element of labels - Arrays are indexed from zero, not 1; so if labels had 6 items, the last one would be labels[5], not labels[6]

Comment: I need it to work as is in that condition. I think I get what's happening. Because its iterating through the results, I think it's comparing twice and buggering up. I need to pass the results to outside the for loop.